# SetState with nested ternary expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this working function that conditionally `setState` of a `searchMode` property, however I have to get rid of the nested ternary expression, how can I do that?

```
  updateSearchMode = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      searchMode:
        prevState.contactsInfo.length === 0
          ? searchModes.noResultsPanel
          : prevState.contactsInfo.length === 0 && prevState.searchString
          ? searchModes.advisoryPanels
          : searchModes.resultsPanel,
    }));
  };
```

Comment: There is no such think as nested ternary operator - it's called *bug*. Expand it to normal IF statement

Comment: @Justinas Sure there is, it's just hard to read (IMO)

Comment: `prevState.contactsInfo.length === 0 && prevState.searchString` will never be true. Because it reaches there only if it fails the first condition `prevState.contactsInfo.length === 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace that ternary expression with regular `if`'s:

```
updateSearchMode = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    if (!prevState.contactsInfo.length && prevState.searchString)
      return ({searchMode: searchModes.advisoryPanels});
    if (!prevState.contactsInfo.length)
      return ({searchMode: searchModes.noResultsPanel});
    return ({searchMode: searchModes.resultsPanel});
  });
};
```

Note that I changed the order a bit as the 2nd case could never be reached because the 1st one would always validate first.

Answer (score 2):

One simplification is you can remove the second `prevState.contactsInfo.length === 0` because you're already checking this condition at start.

```
 prevState.contactsInfo.length === 0
      ? searchModes.noResultsPanel : prevState.searchString
      ? searchModes.advisoryPanels
      : searchModes.resultsPanel,
```

You want to remove `?` operator than you can simply use if else statement.

```
if(prevState.contactsInfo.length === 0){
 ... do whatever you want
} else if(prevState.searchString){
 ... do whatever you want
} else {
... do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: The code could be written that way, but does it accomplish what OP wants? I'm not sure. (with his current code, the second conditional will never be fulfilled.) Unclear if his problem is a linting error or a logic problem (though it does look like a logic problem currently exists)

Comment: @CertainPerformance i have added the if else solution too now. i just wanted to make user aware that he's second condition is not going to be true with the code he has written. OP didn't talked about any error so far in his question. `however I have to get rid of the nested ternary expression, how can I do that?` i considered this and answered.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to simplify a ternary is to write if-else instead. I'm not sure if answers above qualify for the logic you're trying to accomplish but here's what I'd do:

```
updateSearchMode = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    if (prevState.contactsInfo.length === 0) {
      if (prevState.searchString)
        return { searchModes: searchModes.advisoryPanels };
      return { searchModes: searchModes.noResultsPanel };
    }
    return { searchModes: searchModes.resultsPanel };
  });
};
```

You might have to write some test cases for this or manually test all three scenarios for it.